# How can pop-up files/folder information be disabled in FreeCommander?

Tags: windows, freecommander

How do I disable the balloons/popup that appears when a file/folder has been shown for 1-2 seconds in [FreeCommander](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeCommander), v. 2009-02 (screenshot below)?

I am not sure if this is specific to FreeCommander, exactly the same appears in Windows Explorer.

Platform: Windows XP, non-English.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To disable pop-up descriptions in Explorer go to Folder Options -> View tab and uncheck "Show pop-up description for folder and desktop items".

Should also work in FreeCommander if those popups are the same as in Explorer.

**Edit**: I checked the FreeCommander and it's unrelated to Explorer setup. You have a setting for it:

- go to menu Extras -> Settings
- in View settings uncheck "Show files tooltip"

Comment: I added info for Free Commander in the post

Comment: @T. Kaltnekar: that fixed it. Thanks. I have changed the title now that we know it is specific to FreeCommander.